# How to list all available patterns in a SCDynamicStorage?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, scdynamicstore

Considering the following command:

```
sudo scutil
> list
```

I get the list of "pattern" or subkeys available:

```
subKey [0] = Plugin:...
subKey [1] = Setup:....
....
```

Programmatically in Objective-C, I am able to acces a specific  key:

```
SCDynamicStoreRef ds = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nullptr, CFSTR("GetWorkgroup"), nullptr, nullptr);
NSLog(@"Config: %@", SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(ds, CFSTR("State:/Network/Global/IPv4")));
```

However I am struggling in getting all the list of available patterns.

Following program does NOT work:

```
SCDynamicStoreRef ds = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nullptr, CFSTR("GetWorkgroup"), nullptr, nullptr);

const auto  list = SCDynamicStoreCopyKeyList(ds, CFSTR("State:/Network/Service/"));
const size_t keysNum = CFArrayGetCount(list);

std::cout << keysNum << std::endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i< keysNum; ++i)
{
    auto property = static_cast<CFDictionaryRef>(SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(ds, static_cast<CFStringRef>(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(list, i))));
    NSLog(@"Key: %@", property);
}
```

I tried many codes without success. Searching on internet for `SCDynamicStore list subKey` `SCDynamicStore iterate patterns` or similar give little results.

Also, documentation on developer.apple.com, as usual, is useless: no examples, documentation which relay on you already knowing all about it, no #include/#import indication, etc. etc..

## Question

**How to list all available patterns in `SCDynamicStore` ?**

Comment: Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

So, after some research, I found the `SCDynamicStoreCopyMultiple` which has a parameter of type `pattern`: This means it is possible to have regular expression to define the keys.

After discovering this, it was quite easy to implement a prove of concept.

```
SCDynamicStoreRef ds = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nullptr, CFSTR("test"), nullptr, nullptr);
    
const auto keys = CFArrayCreate(nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
const auto keyValue = CFSTR(".*");
const auto patterns = CFArrayCreate(nullptr, (const void**)&keyValue, 1, nullptr);
const CFDictionaryRef  list = SCDynamicStoreCopyMultiple(ds, keys, patterns);

const size_t num = CFDictionaryGetCount(list);
std::vector<CFTypeRef> valuesV(num);
std::vector<CFTypeRef> keysV(num);
CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues(list, keysV.data(), valuesV.data());
    
for (size_t i = 0; i< num; ++i)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", keysV[i], valuesV[i]);
}
```

DISCLAIM: ok, this is not pure Objective-C, but it's trivial to convert it in case.