# How to list virtual network services programatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking, scdynamicstore

### What is needed

Using `scutil`, I may get the list of Network services, including from virtual interfaces (e.g. VPN).

```
scutil
> list
```

Which provides:

```
...
subKey [82] = State:/Network/Service/3EEEA1D1-D35B-427E-BDE0-2025141B495C
subKey [83] = State:/Network/Service/3EEEA1D1-D35B-427E-BDE0-2025141B495C/IPv6
subKey [84] = State:/Network/Service/7B9ECA06-5F37-474A-88A9-CC4EE3638A0E/DHCP
subKey [85] = State:/Network/Service/7B9ECA06-5F37-474A-88A9-CC4EE3638A0E/DNS
subKey [86] = State:/Network/Service/7B9ECA06-5F37-474A-88A9-CC4EE3638A0E/IPv4
subKey [87] = State:/Network/Service/D987D3B3-5AF0-43C8-937E-86B0F8B9D59A
subKey [88] = State:/Network/Service/D987D3B3-5AF0-43C8-937E-86B0F8B9D59A/IPv6
subKey [89] = State:/Network/Service/com.sparklabs.Viscosity.utun10/DNS
subKey [90] = State:/Network/Service/com.sparklabs.Viscosity.utun10/IPv4
subKey [91] = State:/Network/Service/com.sparklabs.Viscosity.utun10/IPv6
```

You may see that first 82-88 are real interfaces, while the last 89-91 is a virtual interface (UTUN) which corresponds to a VPN of type OpenVPN. I need to retrieve this `com.sparklabs.Viscosity.utun10` service name.

### Getting services

**Failing to get services of virtual interfaces**

I am able to list all physical services with the following code:

```
auto prefs = SCPreferencesCreate(nullptr, CFSTR("test"), nullptr);
CFArrayRef services = SCNetworkServiceCopyAll(prefs);
const size_t num = CFArrayGetCount(services);
for (size_t i = 0; i< num; ++i)
{
    NSLog(@"Service: %@", CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(services, i));
}
```

However the result does not include the `UTUN` service:

```
Service: <SCNetworkService 0x7fa2387078b0 [0x7fff84d43cf0]> {id = FDE22A30-76DA-4AE4-963F-FDE4769EAC91, prefs = 0x7fa23840a900}
Service: <SCNetworkService 0x7fa238706430 [0x7fff84d43cf0]> {id = 9EFF9EEA-EE7B-4D85-8DBD-291FA1A80FE5, prefs = 0x7fa23840a900}
Service: <SCNetworkService 0x7fa238706910 [0x7fff84d43cf0]> {id = 3BA8DFA7-C609-4746-A5B5-5A452F6AF44B, prefs = 0x7fa23840a900}
Service: <SCNetworkService 0x7fa238706140 [0x7fff84d43cf0]> {id = 7B9ECA06-5F37-474A-88A9-CC4EE3638A0E, prefs = 0x7fa23840a900}
Service: <SCNetworkService 0x7fa238705de0 [0x7fff84d43cf0]> {id = A14CD980-C388-4A5D-8DE5-493B62D78A60, prefs = 0x7fa23840a900}
```

### Getting interfaces

**Failing to get the service related to the interface**

Interfaces, including virtual one are quite easy to retrieve:

```
SCDynamicStoreRef ds = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nullptr, CFSTR("test"), nullptr, nullptr);
    
const auto  list = SCDynamicStoreCopyKeyList(ds, CFSTR("State:/Network/Interface"));
const size_t num = CFArrayGetCount(list);
for (size_t i = 0; i< num; ++i)
{
    auto key = static_cast<CFStringRef>(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(list, i));
    auto value = static_cast<CFDictionaryRef>(SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(ds, key));
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, value);
}
```

With the following result:

```
State:/Network/Interface = {
    Interfaces =     (
        ...
        en0,
        en1,
        ...
        utun10
    );
}
```

However, I am not able to get the service interface related to them, thus.

## Question

**How to list virtual network services?**

### Related questions

[How to list all available patterns in a SCDynamicStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393276/how-to-list-all-available-patterns-in-a-scdynamicstorage)

[Finding DNS server settings programmatically on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260518/finding-dns-server-settings-programmatically-on-mac-os-x)